# angular-material bottom sheet issue with mobile browser?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, mobile-browser, bottom-sheet

[image]

this is my bottom-sheet its working properly in pc's browser and swipe-down event is doing well in it but in mobile's browser it starts reloading and I have to click out side for closing bottom sheet is there any other way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it Bottom-sheet will work properly if you add overflow-y to none in body element so it will prevent pull-to-refresh event !